# Word VBA Find Using Wildcards

Tags: vba, ms-word, row, wildcard, word-table

I have a word table and it is having 2000 rows. Each row contains some EXTENT i.e. area of land in square yards(Sq. Yds) from 10 Sq. yds to 70000 sq. yds. I have to filter it, need rows having Extent more than 500 Sq. Yds. Among 2000 rows I want to filter these rows using Wildcards in VBA Word Macro in such a way that I shall get Extent of 500 and more than it leaving rows below 500 Sq. yds. The text to be found is combination of characters and number. I want to filter finding "EXTENT: ([5-9][0-9][0-9])". "EXTENT: XXXX"(number digits).

```
Sub FilterExtentUsingWildcards()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim TblRng As Range, TmpRng As Range
  With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set TblRng = .Range: Set TmpRng = .Range
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "<EXTENT:><space>([3-9][0-9][0-9])" 'FindText which is combination of
        'characters, space and Number
        .MatchWildcards = True                'i.e. "EXTENT: XXXX(number digits)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found
        If .InRange(TblRng) Then
          TmpRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          TmpRng.FormattedText = .Rows(1).Range.FormattedText
          .Rows(1).Delete
        End If
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
    If .Rows.Count > TblRng.Rows.Count Then
      .Split .Rows(TblRng.Rows.Count + 1)
    End If
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question so is will be more readable. As it show now it's difficult to help about this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in your code says that you are looking for "EXTENT: 300" and above, but `Find.Text` doesn't include the space. You then turn MatchWildcards on and 7 lines later turn it off.

I have edited your code as below:

```
Sub FilterExtentUsingWildcards()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim TblRng As Range, TmpRng As Range
  With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Set TblRng = .Range: Set TmpRng = .Range
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .text = "EXTENT: ([5-9][0-9][0-9])" 'FindText which is combination of characters, space and Number
        .MatchWildcards = True 'i.e. "EXTENT: XXXX(number digits)
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
      End With
      Do While .Find.Found
        If .InRange(TblRng) Then
          TmpRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          TmpRng.FormattedText = .Rows(1).Range.FormattedText
          .Rows(1).Delete
        End If
        .Find.Execute
      Loop
    End With
    If .Rows.Count > TblRng.Rows.Count Then
      .Split .Rows(TblRng.Rows.Count + 1)
    End If
    'uncomment the next line if you want to delete the original table
    '.Delete
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Dear Timothy Rylatt sir, thanks for offering Answer to my question immediately.  I have tried by editing the macro as you suggested but still not working.

Comment: @Sampath - I tested the code and it works, but as you haven't described in your question what results you are expecting I cannot know whether it does what you want it to. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use the edit link below your question to provide more detail.

Comment: Thank you for quick response to me sir. Sir I have a word Table and it is having 2000 rows. Each row contains some EXTENT i.e. area of land in square yards(Sq. Yds)  from 10 Sq. yds to 70000 sq. yds. I have to filter it, need rows having Extent more than 500 Sq. Yds. Among 2000 rows I want to filter these rows using Wildcards in VBA Word Macro in such a way that I shall get Extent of 500 and more than it leaving rows below 500 Sq. yds. The text to be found is combination of characters and number. I want to filter finding "EXTENT: <single space>([5-9][0-9][0-9])". "EXTENT: XXXX"(number digits).

Comment: @Sampath I have edited my answer and provided you with the full code for your routine. When asked to provide more detail please use the edit link below your question rather than adding a comment.

Comment: Thank You very much Sir. It is working perfectly and fetching the intended result.

Comment: @Sampath - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)